# как выдавать роль за сообщение

Tags: python, discord.py

выдача роли '「」Казино 777'   за сообщение 'pon'

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
ROLE_KASINO: discord.Role = ...

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content != 'pon':
        return
    await message.author.add_role(ROLE_KASINO)
```

Comment: а у вас айди нужно или что

Comment: @adites да, айди роли

Comment: а в кавычках или без

Comment: @adites нет....